# Hugo Date vs PublishDate

Tags: hugo

Hugo offers a few date page variables:

- `Date` - the date associated with the page
- `PublishDate` - the date on which the content was or will be published
- `LastMod` - the date the content was last modified
- `ExpiryDate` - the date on which the content is scheduled to expire

`LastMod` and `ExpiryDate` make sense to me, but I am puzzled as to the difference between `Date` and `PublishDate`.

What are some examples of when `Date` and `PublishDate` are different?

Comment: An observation is that `.PublishDate` returns `.Date` when it is not explicitly specified.

Comment: I discovered that Date behavior is configurable.  See https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#configure-dates

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If...

1. you are using the default meaning of `date` and `publishDate` (see below),
2. both are defined for a page,
3. and `date` is different from `publishDate`

Then...

- `publishDate` is used to determine if a page is in the future (i.e. if hugo's `-F` or `--buildFuture` flag is required for the page to be built)
- `date` is used to order pages in the default ordering (Weight > Date > LinkTitle > Title > FilePath).[*] The default order is used in next/previous navigation and can be used in a `range`.

Configuring dates is discussed in https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#configure-front-matter. Here is the default for `date` and `publishDate`:

```
frontmatter:
  date:
    - date
    - publishDate
    - lastmod
  publishDate:
    - publishDate
    - date
```

Because I want `date` and `publishDate` to mean the same thing, I have the following in my `config.yaml`:

```
frontmatter:
  date: 
    - publishDate
    - :filename
    - date
    - :fileModTime
  publishDate: 
    - publishDate
    - :filename
    - date
    - :fileModTime
```

I've made them the same because I, too, was puzzled by their difference!

[*] Info about ordering content in Hugo is at https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/#order-content